# How to make the YouTube player from embedded iframe work and not block the page load in Chrome?

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a web page with this code in it (hidden by default with `display: none` ancestor) (please see the screenshots below):

```html
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YAGuGFpeIJA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The YouTube API calls timeout and in plus my Chrome browser gets blocked (the DevTools cannot be opened in that tab - to make the screenshots I had to open the DevTools before navigating to that web page; the context menu on the page content does not get opened). The code runs on a local Docker container. I believe the issue is linked to the URL of the web page, because the issue happens only after putting this code at the end of my WordPress theme's `functions.php`:

```php
add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules');
function rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $new_rules = array(
        '/ro/.*$' => 'index.php',
        '/en/.*$' => 'index.php'
    );
    return $rules + $new_rules;
}
```

[This](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) page sent me here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62102828/258462) is a previous question in the same "series".

**Update:** The page is still blocked if I remove the src attribute of the iframe, but at least the spinner starts to fade-out. It fades out just partially, and then again I cannot open DevTools in the usual manner. In the Network tab of DevTools I see that it may be a WP REST API call that is the problem:

[image: update screenshot]

Below are just the screenshots - the last part of the actual question.

Thank you.

## Screenshots

### 1

[image: 1]

### 2

[image: 2]

### 3

[image: 3]

### 4

[image: 4]

### 5

[image: 5]

### 6

[image: 6]

### 7

[image: 7]

### 8

[image: 8]

### 9

[image: 9]

### 10

[image: 10]

Comment: What happens if you give the iframe no `src` and via javascript define that value when needed?

Comment: @GetSet I updated the question with a new part (bolded "**Update:**"). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the exact cause and how it should behave ideally, but to solve this in my case I just had to do this:

> Furthermore, permalinks will need to be refreshed (you can do this from your admin under (Settings > Permalinks) before the rewrite changes will take effect.

(step taken from https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)